# Im not getting the right results when i enter in my output

Tags: python-3.x

Create a change-counting game that gets the user to enter the number of coins required to make exactly one dollar. 
main
This contains the mainline logic for the program. It performs the following actions: Ask the user to enter number of:
o Pennies
o Nickels
o Dimes
o quarters Convert the user input values into int values. 
Invoke the computeValue function and send in these 4 variables as arguments.

Calculate and display total dollar amount as pennies. 
When total Pennies is exactly equal to 1 dollar, print out a message. 
If computed value is less than $1, display the amount with the message indicating that the value is less than a dollar, and print out the amount 
If computer value is greater than a dollar, display the dollar amount and the cents separately. See sample output for examples.

My sample out consist of 5,3,3,2 and I'm suppose to get "i  have 1 dollar and 25 cents" instead i am getting i have 5 dollars and 5 cents.

```
def main():
    pennies=int(input("Enter the Number of pennies : "))
    nickels = int(input("Enter the Number of nickels : "))
    dimes = int(input("Enter the Number of dimes : "))
    quarters =int(input("Enter the Number of quarters : "))

    pennies1=pennies*1
    nickels1=nickels*5
    dimes1=dimes*10
    quarters1=quarters*25

    total=pennies1 +nickels1+dimes1+quarters1
    cash=total//100
    change=total-cash*100
    computeValue(pennies1,nickels1,dimes1,quarters1)

def computeValue(pennies1,nickels1,dimes1,quarters1):
    print("You entered")
    if (pennies1 == 1):
        print ("You have exactely 1 dollar")
    elif (pennies1 < 1):
        print ("You have",pennies1,"which is less than 1 dollar")
    elif (pennies1 > 1):
        print ("pennies:",pennies1,"\nnickels:",nickels1,"\ndimes:",dimes1,
        "\nquarters:",quarters1,"\nYou have",pennies1,"dollars and",pennies1,"cents")

main()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you $1.00, not $1.25. Also you should probably be using 100 for your comparison in the `computeValue` function rather than 1. you have 1 dollar if `pennies1 == 100`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your program is very confused about how to calculate the value.
2. `5*1 + 2*5 + 2*10 + 2*25 = 100`, not `125`
3. you write `pennies1, "dollars and", pennies1,  "cents"` which makes no sense.

This should work as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pennies = int(input("Enter the Number of pennies : "))
    nickels = int(input("Enter the Number of nickels : "))
    dimes = int(input("Enter the Number of dimes : "))
    quarters = int(input("Enter the Number of quarters : "))

    cents = pennies
    cents += nickels*5
    cents += dimes*10
    cents += quarters*25

    dollars = int(cents / 100) 
    cents = cents % 100 

    print ("You entered {} pennies {} nickels {} dimes and {} quarters".format(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters))
    print ("You have {} dollars and {} cents".format(dollars,cents))

    if dollars == 1 and cents == 0:
      print("You Win")
    else:
      print("you fail")
```

---

**[edit]:** You can add some functions to break things down if you want:

```
def change_to_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    cents = pennies
    cents += nickels*5
    cents += dimes*10
    cents += quarters*25
    return cents

def display_change(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    print ("You entered {} pennies {} nickels {} dimes and {} quarters".format(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters))

def display_cents(cents):
    dollars = int(cents / 100) 
    cents = cents % 100
    print ("You have {} dollars and {} cents".format(dollars,cents))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pennies = int(input("Enter the Number of pennies : "))
    nickels = int(input("Enter the Number of nickels : "))
    dimes = int(input("Enter the Number of dimes : "))
    quarters = int(input("Enter the Number of quarters : "))

    display_change(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)        

    cents = change_to_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    display_cents(cents)

    if cents == 100:
        print("You Win")
    else:
        print("you fail")
```

Comment: thank you. how would you incorporate invoking the computeValue function and sending the variables in to an argument?

Comment: @DaveLee What do you want the `computeValue` function to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest answer:

```
penny = int(input('Enter the number of pennies: '))
nickel = int(input('Enter the number of nickels: '))
dime = int(input('Enter the number of dimes: '))
quarters = int(input('Enter the number of quarters: '))
PENNIES = 100
NICKELS = 20
DIMES = 10
QUARTERS = 4
dollar = (penny / PENNIES) + (nickel / NICKELS) + (dime / DIMES) + (quarters / QUARTERS)
if dollar == 1:
    print("Congratulations! You've entered one dollar!")
elif dollar > 1:
    print("Sorry! You've entered more than one dollar")
else:
    print("Sorry! You've entered less than one dollar")
```